# How to explain thesis topic/advisor change during masters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor

I changed my master's advisor after working on a thesis topic for several months. Then, even though I liked the research domain (computational study), I felt the project was all over the place and I simply lost my faith in my advisor.

I found a more suitable advisor on an experimental project.

How do I address this issue? I am interested in computational work for PhD, and I am worried about how it would look when I changed from a computational project to experimental in the masters.

Would it help if I had computational experience in the undergradute?

Comment: What is wrong with explaining it like you did here?

Answer (score -1):

Tell him how you feel, in the end the one putting effort is you and not him.